# \stackrel with \sim symbol

Tags: stacking-symbols

I am using `\stackrel{<}{\sim}` to stack up two symbols. However I need to lower `\sim`, which naturally goes above the line, otherwise `<`raises too. This is the output at the moment:

[image: example of my output]

Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! There is no need to 'sign' your question, as your name appears on the question automatically.

Comment: Have a look at [“How to look up a math symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Answer (score 16):

The `amssymb` package offers you `\lesssim`, and, as egreg comments, the `wasysym` package offers `\apprle`, which raises the tilde a little bit. Here they are, side by side:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}

$T\lesssim S \qquad T\apprle S$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `MnSymbol` package also implements a `\lesssim`, which is a more compact variation of its `amssymb` homonymous (caution: loading `amssymb` and `MnSymbol` simultaneously will result in name clash).

Comment: Otherwise `\apprle` from the **wasysym** package, which seems to raise the tilde a bit.

Comment: @egreg: I added your suggestion to my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The obligatory Unicode solution:

```
% Just to get the needed fonts for the example up and running with Plain.
% You'd also need the mapping-files for this to work.
% For LaTeX, I think that unicode-math sets all of these up.
\def\mathfont{Asana Math}
\def\lfont#1#2#3{%
  \expandafter\font\csname#1\endcsname="\mathfont:script=math;mapping=#2" at 10pt
  \expandafter\font\csname#1s\endcsname="\mathfont:script=math;+ssty=0;mapping=#2" at 7pt
  \expandafter\font\csname#1ss\endcsname="\mathfont:script=math;+ssty=1;mapping=#2" at 5pt
  \textfont#3=\csname#1\endcsname
  \scriptfont#3=\csname#1s\endcsname
  \scriptscriptfont#3=\csname#1ss\endcsname}
\lfont{mathrm}{roman}{0}
\textfont3=\mathrm \scriptfont3=\mathrms \scriptscriptfont3=\mathrmss
\lfont{mathit}{italic}{1} % you could go on with \lfont{mathbf}{bold}{6} etc.
% end of makeshift font loading
\XeTeXmathchardef\lesssim="3"1`≲ % for LaTeX with unicode-math, this is already set.
$ T \lesssim S $
\bye
```

Which looks like:
[image: lesssim]

Comment: `unicode-math` indeed defines `\lesssim` for ≲.

Comment: Thanks all, all your answers have been really helpful to me. \lesssim works fine for me, and the symbol looks way better than before in my thesis!